# jq (map(select))Cannot index string with string "ID" exit status 5

Tags: jq

data:

```
[{"id": "first", "val": 1}, {"id": "second", "val": 2}, {"id": "second", "val": 3}]
```

query:

```
.[] | map(select(.id == "second"))
```

expected:

```
{"id": "second", "val": 2}, {"id": "second", "val": 3}
```

result:

```
Cannot index string with string "id"
```

https://jqplay.org/jq?q=.%5B%5D%20%7C%20select(.id%20%3D%3D%20%22second%22)&j=%5B%7B%22id%22%3A%20%22first%22%2C%20%22val%22%3A%201%7D%2C%20%7B%22id%22%3A%20%22second%22%2C%20%22val%22%3A%202%7D%5D

Why could be this result?

Answer (score 2):

`map(select(.id == "second"))` expects an array of objects, however `.[]` takes them out of the array so everything after that must be able to work on single item.

In your jqplay example your filter is `.[] | select(.id == "second")` and is working fine.

It should be obvious now how to fix your issue ;)